# Django - TinyMCE - admin - How to change editor size?

Tags: python, django, tinymce, django-tinymce

I can't seem to find any way to hange editor size in TinyMCE.
I edit posts on my site in Django administration and to make it easier I looked for a better editor than just a textfield. I succesfully installed TinyMCE, but the editor is tiny, which makes editing very annoying.

[Here's how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEPHn.png)

Here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from tinymce.models import HTMLField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    # body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = HTMLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

And here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:25],
        template_name='blog/blog.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$',
        DetailView.as_view(model=Post,
                           template_name='blog/post.html')),
]
```

I've been trying and googling for the past 2 hours, but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: if you use this plugin: https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce, then in the docs (http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration) you can see a TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG setting which can be used to config the editor, and here you can find some options: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/, so try adding something like `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {'theme': "simple", 'relative_urls': False, 'width': '100%', 'height': 300}` in your settings.py

Comment: It worked, thank you :)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer to help people searching for the same answer. Feel free to accept it, it is more evident for people having the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As said in the docs (http://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration), there is the `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` setting which can be used to configure the editor. Just look for available options here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/.

In your case, I think something like this may work:

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "simple", # default value
    'relative_urls': False, # default value
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 300
}
```

Put it in your settings.py

Comment: I figured I was using an older version, so I downloaded a newer one and now the editor [looks great](https://horeckyt.com/static/images/editor_new.png)

Answer (score 2):

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG dictionary needs to set in the settings.py file.

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "advanced",
    'width' : 758,
    'height' : 118,
}
```

This will change width and height of the tinymce editor.

Comment: a bit late to the party, uh?

Comment: Hey I am in the party. Do join us :p

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do exactly this - change the TinyMCE admin widget size - but not change the whole/default configuration for all of the widgets. Here was my solution:

```py
class SomeModelClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "description":
            return db_field.formfield(
                widget=TinyMCE(
                    mce_attrs={"height": "200"},
                )
            )
        return super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

TLDR: in your `admin.py`, within the model admin class, override `formfield_for_dbfield` with the above.

This only changes the height for the model field called `description` rather than all admin tinycme widgets. Hope this can be useful! It took me a while to figure it out :-)